# Solution to pde $f_x =a f +b+ c$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have $f = f(x,y)$, $a,b,c$ - constants:
I can not come u with defining the name of the PDE, nor how to solve it.
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = a f + b + c$$

First thing I thought of looking at simpler case, and treat partial derivative as not that one

(**is it valid to do like this?**):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = a f$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{f} = a \partial x$$
$$ln(f) - ln (f_0) = a  (x - x_0)$$
$$f = f_0 e^{ a  (x - x_0)}$$
Now I am looking at books of Evans for PDEs and Polyanin handbook but can not find what is it.

Comment: 1) You've got $f_t$ in your title but $\partial f/\partial x$ in your question. Which one do you mean? 2) In what sense is this a PDE? As written, there's only one kind of derivative and so this would just be an ODE.

Comment: 1)pardon, I did typo. Let it be $x$.2) I assume this is pde as in general function is of variables $x,y$.

Comment: I'd say it's still an ODE, since you only differentiate with respect to $x$. Hence for the purposes of the problem you can treat $y$ as though it's just another unknown, just as $a,b,c$ are. The method you propose will therefore -almost- work; however, you can't drop the terms $b,c$ and you have to allow the constants of integration to depend on $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $b$ and $c$ are both constants, let $d := b+c$. The differential equation is

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = af + d$$

Since there are no derivatives with respect to $y$, we can solve this like an ODE - we only have to be careful when considering the constants of integration.

By separation of variables, we have

$$\int\frac{df}{af+d} = \int dx$$

Calculating the integrals, we have

$$\frac{1}{a}\log|af+d| = x + g(y)$$

What would be a constant of integration on the RHS in an ODE is an arbitrary function of $y$, as this will vanish when taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$.

\begin{align*}
&\log|af+d| = ax+ag(y)\\
&\Rightarrow|af+d| = e^{ag(y)}e^{ax} \\
&\Rightarrow af = \pm e^{ag(y)}e^{ax} -d \\
&\Rightarrow f(x,y) = \frac{G(y)e^{ax} - d}{a}
\end{align*}

where $G(y) := \pm e^{ag(y)}$ is another arbitrary function of $y$.

Comment: Thank you for reply! Could you name this type of ODE (or PDE)? Is it a 1st order ODE, so I can read more about it?

Comment: It's a first order linear ODE with constant coefficients. They're the easiest type to solve and have been studied extensively, so you should have no problem finding material online or in textbooks. Good luck! :)